# How to include a sidebar in Laravel to show on all pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to show a sidebar that displays data from the database across all my pages in Laravel, but I keep getting this error:

> Undefined variable: products (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\resources\views\pages\sidebar.blade.php) (View:

**Sidebar**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
<nav class=" d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <form>
            <div class=" input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <span id="catName">{{ $product->name }}</span>
            <h2>No category to show</h2>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $product = Product::get();

    return view('pages.sidebar', ['products' => $product]);    
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::resource('sidebar','SidebarController');
```

**app.blade.php**

```php
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
    @include('pages.sidebar')
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do `@include()` or your can return it via a controller, you cannot do both. I think you might be a little mixed up with the structure of your project.

If you are using `@include` it isn't going to hit a controller. So in theory, you would need to include `['products' => $products]` on every controller method.

Here is how I would do it:

sidebar.blade.php:

```html
<nav class=" d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-sticky">
        <form>
            <div class=" input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <span id="catName">{{ $product->name }}</span>
            <h2>No category to show</h2>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</nav>
```

app.blade.php:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
    @include('pages.sidebar')
</div>
```

Create a new file (or use an existing one) for a home page inside the pages folder, we will call it `home.blade.php`

home.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Change the view you are returning in the controller to new `home.blade.php` file.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $product = Product::get();

        return view('pages.home', ['products' => $product]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please I need a little clarification . Please  will the home file replace the sidebar.blade? and how do i display the home.blade since when I use @include the controller will not be hit

Answer (score 0):

I finally have to use view composer to solve this problem. Thank you